# How to get a random list every time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I am trying to make a random list (subcommittee) of 3 students from committee. Then, I want to print a new random subcommittee 1000 times. Right now, the code I have is printing the same subcommittee 1000 times. How can I fix this?

```
import random

undergrads = ["ug_1", "ug_2", "ug_3", "ug_4"]
grads = ["g_1", "g_2"]
committee = undergrads + grads

subcommittee = []
for i in range(3):
    add_sub = random.choice(committee)
    subcommittee.append(add_sub)

for j in range(1000):
    print subcommittee
```

Comment: Have you considered putting the randomization part of your code inside the loop...?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you think that printing a `list` repeatedly would produce random results each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because you are creating a `subcommittee` with 3 random members, and then reprinting that randomly predefined list `1000` times (an xkcd comes to mind here): [image: (An xkcd comes to mind here)]

To fix this do something like:

```
for i in range(1000):
    subcommittee = []
    for i in range(3):
        add_sub = random.choice(committee)
        subcommittee.append(add_sub)
    print subcommittee
```

You could also just do this:

```
for i in range(1000):
    print([random.choice(committee) for _ in range(3)])
```

Or better yet, use a [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
for i in range(1000):
    print(random.sample(committee, 3))
```